# java compiler, finding the follow producing duplicates

Tags: java, compiler-construction

ive been working on a java compiler assignment that is asking to find the First of a grammar. I have it all ready and done. all the work has been done , but i have one problem. my first is producing duplicates. for example part of my output is this

```
NonTerminal      First
     P          int void                                
     L          int void                                
     D          int void                                
     Vd         int void                                
     Ts         int void                                
     Fn         int void                                
     Ps         int void void
```

Ps int void void  , the 2nd void is a duplicate. how would i go about removing these duplicates? ill paste my main compiler code were everything happens below.
i suspect i would have to make a change somewere in the findFirst method, since thats were all the action happens , but im not sure what to do.

```
package compilerproject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Compiler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Grammar> gList = getGrammar(); 
        Map<String, List<String>> fList = firstList(gList);
        //firstlist returns a hash map LHS and RHS
        //save it into fList which is a map of Strings and List so u can use it in findFirst method
       printFirstList(fList, gList);
       ParserLibrary idList = new ParserLibrary();

    }

    public static List<String> findFirst(String v, List<Grammar> l)
    {
        List<String> First = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
        {

            if(v.equals(l.get(i).term))
            {


                String [] s = l.get(i).prod.split(" ");

                if(!isNonTerm(s[0]))// is a terminal
                {
                    First.add(s[0]);
                }

    // if the rhs is a terminal
```

Comment: Don't expect other people to debug your code, especially not when it's 240 lines long, not compilable, don't have any comments inside what do you expect it to do.

Comment: theres 3 only  methods , i explain what the program does and what i want it to do. chill , Im new and  trying

Comment: what your code does ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would save some troubles using a Set instead of a List.
I kept List as return type, but changed the rest.

```
public static List<String> findFirst(String v, List<Grammar> l) {
    Set<String> first = new TreeSet<>();

    Set<String> done = new HashSet<>();
    done.add(v);

    Grammer previous = null;
    for (Grammar gr : l) {
        if (v.equals(gr.term)) {
            String s = gr.prod.split(" ")[0];
            if (!isNonTerm(s)) { // is a terminal
                first.add(s);
            }

            // if the rhs is a terminal 
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("empty") && previous != null) {
                String[] stemp = previous.prod.split(" ");

                if (v.equalsIgnoreCase(stemp[0]) && stemp.length > 1
                        && done.add(stemp[1])) {
                    first.addAll(findFirst(stemp[1], l)); // <--------- Here it happened
                }
                //if the rhs is empty , then get the previous grammar 
                //split it.
                //find the first of it and ad it to the first list
            }
            if (!v.equals(s) && isNonTerm(s) && done.add(s)) {
                first.addAll(findFirst(s, l));
            }
        }
        previous = gr;       
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(first);
}
```

I still do not find the code entirely clear. So maybe with `Set` at your disposal, you may find a simpler formulation. To remove the scroll bar I place the open brace on the same line.

To prevent endless recursion I added the set `done` which "evidently" is not needed.

Comment: i was looking at sets , it seems this is the easiest method to solve this. im just trying to understand the changes you made. They seem a lil different than what i had before lol